# Windows Properties tab not showing all info, varies across systems

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, metadata

I wanted to check the sample rate on an audio file that I had, so I right-clicked the file in my Windows Explorer and selected "Properties." However, on my machine, there's no mention of sample rate and the metadata only displays the bit rate.

[image: Here's what it looks like.]

I asked my friend about it, and he claimed that he could see the sample rate of audio files on his computer when he did the exact same thing (and viewed the Properties of a file in Windows Explorer).

[image: Here's what his properties tab looks like.]

The difference is staggering: his properties has much more detail. He says he doesn't remember downloading any external software to get it to look like this, but we're running the exact same Windows build (10.0.18362).

Any ideas as to what he may have done to make his Properties tab look like this? I tried poking around in the "View" settings of File Explorer but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend's screenshot says [dBpoweramp](https://www.dbpoweramp.com/) in the corner. That's external software.

Comment: Thanks so much! I asked my friend and he presumes that his grandfather installed it on his PC before it was given to him. All this time, he thought that his properties tab was the norm for Windows and was very shocked to find out it was an external program :)